# How to create a vector in R in the pattern (0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3...len(list/2))

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create an index for a data frame. Each team playing has its own row, but I would like to add a column to use as an index so that the first two teams have the index 'Game 0', the next two teams have the index 'Game 1' until the length of half the list. In python the code would look as follows:

```
for i in range(0,int(len(teams)/2)):
     gamenumber.append('Game '+str(i))
     gamenumber.append('Game '+str(i))
```

I am unfamiliar with R so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of paired index numbers:

```
> teams=1:100
> data.frame("Games"=sort(c(1:(length(teams)/2), 1:(length(teams)/2))))
    Games
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       2
5       3
6       3
7       4
8       4
9       5
10      5
11      6
12      6
13      7
14      7
15      8
16      8
17      9
18      9
19     10
20     10 #etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `teams` is a data.frame with an even number of rows:

```
rep(1:(nrow(teams)/2), each=2)
```